# Cant make my navigation bar fit all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on my navigation bar i have 5pages Home,About US,Recently Passed,Areas,Contact

The contact seems to go underneath.

i have tried making the font smaller but i still haven thad any lucky would someone pleas ebeable to help me out.

here is the link to the website for a preview - http://leetaxi.webuda.com/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Graduate School Of Motoring</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scripts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css">

<!-- Change Color Stylesheet Here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/default.css">


<!-- TEMPLATE STYLESHEETS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">

<!-- REVOLUTION BANNER CSS SETTINGS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen" />


<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<!--[if lt ie 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">you are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. please <a   href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

<div class="preloader"><i class="fa fa-spinner spin"></i></div>


<!-- SLIDER -->
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="rev-slider">
        <ul>
            <!-- SLIDE #1  -->
            <li data-transition="fade" data-masterspeed="1000" data-delay="6000" >
                <!-- BACKGROUND -->
                <img src="img/slider/bg-1.jpg" alt="">

                <!-- BIG TEXT -->
                <h1 class="tp-caption caption-title2 sft"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-speed="1000">
                    <img src="img/slider/main.png" width="390" height="108">
                </h1>

                <!-- LIST -->
                <div class="tp-caption slider-list sfb"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-voffset="50"
                    data-speed="500"
                    data-splitin="chars"
                    data-splitout="chars"
                    data-start="1500"
                    data-elementdelay="0.04">
                </div><!-- End .tp-caption -->
            </li>

            <li data-transition="fade" data-masterspeed="1000" data-delay="6000" >
                <!-- BACKGROUND -->
                <img src="img/slider/bg-2.jpg" alt="">

                <!-- BIG TEXT -->
                <h1 class="tp-caption caption-title2 sft"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-speed="1000">
                    <img src="img/slider/main.png" width="390" height="108">
                </h1>

                <!-- LIST -->
                <div class="tp-caption slider-list sfb"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-voffset="50"
                    data-speed="500"
                    data-splitin="chars"
                    data-splitout="chars"
                    data-start="1500"
                    data-elementdelay="0.04">
                </div><!-- End .tp-caption -->
            </li>

            <!-- SLIDE #2  -->
            <li data-transition="fade" data-masterspeed="1000" data-delay="6000" >
                <!-- BACKGROUND -->
                <img src="img/slider/bg-3.jpg" alt="">

                <!-- BIG TEXT -->
                <h1 class="tp-caption caption-title2 sft"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-speed="1000">
                    <img src="img/slider/main.png" width="390" height="108">
                </h1>

                <!-- LIST -->
                <div class="tp-caption slider-list sfb"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-voffset="50"
                    data-speed="500"
                    data-splitin="chars"
                    data-splitout="chars"
                    data-start="1500"
                    data-elementdelay="0.04">
                </div><!-- End .tp-caption -->
            </li>

            <!-- SLIDE #3 -->
            <li data-transition="fade" data-masterspeed="1000" data-delay="6000" >
                <!-- BACKGROUND -->
                <img src="img/slider/bg-4.jpg" alt="">

                <!-- BIG TEXT -->
                <h1 class="tp-caption caption-title2 sft"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-speed="1000">
                    <img src="img/slider/main.png" width="390" height="108">
                </h1>

                <!-- LIST -->
                <div class="tp-caption slider-list sfb"
                    data-y="center"
                    data-x="center"
                    data-voffset="50"
                    data-speed="500"
                    data-splitin="chars"
                    data-splitout="chars"
                    data-start="1500"
                    data-elementdelay="0.04">
                </div><!-- End .tp-caption -->
            </li>

        </ul>
   </div><!-- End .rev-slider -->
    </div><!-- End .slider-wrapper -->


   <div class="header">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- LOGO -->
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" width="70" alt="Horizon">
        </a>

        <ul id="sn" class="main_menu">
            <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#portfolio">Recently Passed</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#services">Areas</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!-- End .main-menu -->
    </div><!-- End .container -->
   </div><!-- End .header -->


    <!-- ABOUT -->
    <section id="about" class="sect-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h1 class="title">About Us</h1>
        <p class="description">These are some of the services we offer
          </li></div></p>
      <div align="center"><ul class="features">
          <p>At Graduate School of Motoring, we have been providing quality driving instruction to    all abilities for over 20 years.</p>
          <p>We have both male and female instructors to make you feel comfortable and at ease at all times during your learning experience. Our lessons are always challenging, fun and kept at a pace to suit you. At Graduate School of Motoring, we understand how important it is to have a driving instructor that matches your personality.</p>
          <p>This is why we have male and female instructors available, and all our instructors are friendly and patient. We know how unnerving driving a car can be, so we always work with you, instantly recognising your strengths and working on the weaknesses.</p>
          <p>We also have refresher lessons available for all ages.</p>
          <p>Why choose Graduate School of Motoring?<br>
            Incredibly quick pass rate<br>
            Male and female instructors available<br>
            Long serving company with bags of experience<br>
            Great block deals<br>
            Refresher lessons available<br>
            Friendly and patient instructors<br>
            1st lesson is free of charge<br>
            All ages welcome<br>
          Pass plus available</p>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End .container -->
  </section>


   <!-- PORTFOLIO -->
   <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio-wrapper sect-2">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="section-title">
            <h1 class="title">Recent Passes</h1>
            <p class="description">These are some of our pupils that have recently passed.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- CATEGORIES -->
        <ul class="filter-menu">
            <li class="selected" data-cat="*">All</li>
        </ul><!-- End .filter-menu -->
    </div><!-- End .container -->

    <!-- HOOK FOR PROJECT VIEWER -->
    <div class="project-wrapper"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="portfolio clearfix">
            <!-- ITEM 1 -->
            <div class="port-item showme" data-cat="branding">
                <div class="port-overlay">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/port-1.jpg" alt="Portfolio Image">
                    <a class="project-btn" href="single-project.html"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="port-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                    <span class="port-cat">James Youells</span>
                    <span class="port-name">Passed</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 2 -->
            <div class="port-item showme" data-cat="photography">
                <div class="port-overlay">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/port-2.jpg" alt="Portfolio Image">
                    <a class="project-btn" href="single-project-full.html"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>   </a>
                </div>
                <div class="port-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                    <span class="port-cat">Lisa Jones</span>
                    <span class="port-name">Passed</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 3 -->
            <div class="port-item showme" data-cat="branding">
                <div class="port-overlay">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/port-3.jpg" alt="Portfolio Image">
                    <a class="lightbox-btn" data-pp="prettyPhoto"  href="img/portfolio/port-3.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="port-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                    <span class="port-cat">Sam Smith</span>
                    <span class="port-name">Passed</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 4-->
            <div class="port-item showme" data-cat="art">
                <div class="port-overlay">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/port-4.jpg" alt="Portfolio Image">
                    <a class="project-btn" href="single-project.html"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="port-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                    <span class="port-cat">Samantha Tom</span>
                    <span class="port-name">Passed</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ROW 2 -->

            <!-- ITEM 5 --><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 6 --><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 7 --><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 8--><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ROW 3 -->

            <!-- ITEM 9 --><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 10 --><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 11 --><!-- End port item -->

            <!-- ITEM 12 --><!-- End port item -->

        </div><!-- End .portfolio -->
    </div><!-- End .container -->

    <a href="index.html#" id="load-more" class="button outline">Load more</a>
    </section>


   <!-- CALLOUT -->
   <section id="services" class="sect-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="callout">
            <h3 class="title">We can help you if you are in:                  </h3>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h3 class="title"><a href="index.html#contact" class="button outline">Call Us</a> </h3>
        </div><!-- End .callout -->

      <ul class="feature-imgs">
            <li class="one-third animated" data-animate="flipInY">
                <div class="feature-hex">
                    <img src="img/features/features-1.jpg" alt="feature image 1" />
                </div>

                <h4 class="title">Gravesend<br>Dartford<br>Swanscombe<br>Darenth</h4>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </li>
            <li class="one-third animated middle" data-animate="flipInY" data-animate-delay="1500">
                <div class="feature-hex">
                    <img src="img/features/features-2.jpg" alt="feature image 2" />
                </div>

                <h4 class="title">Medway Towns<br>New Ash Green<br>Borough Green<br>Wrotham</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="one-third animated last" data-animate="flipInY" data-animate-delay="2000">
                <div class="feature-hex">
                    <img src="img/features/features-3.jpg" alt="feature image 2" />
                </div>

                <h4 class="title">Sevenoak<br>Sidcup<br>Erith<br>Belverdere</h4>
            </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- End .container -->
   </section>

 <!-- TESTIMONIALS --><!-- CLIENTS -->
 <div class="clients"><!-- End .container -->
 </div><!-- End .clients -->


  <!-- TEAM -->
<section class="sect-2">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="section-title">
            <h3 class="title">OUR DRIVERS</h3>
</div>

        <ul class="team">
            <li class="one-fourth animated" data-animate="flipInY">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="img/team/team-1.jpg" alt="Team Member">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="team-name">John Green</span>
                <span class="team-job"></span>
                <ul class="social-icons">
                </ul><!-- End .social-icons -->
            </li><!-- End .one-fourth -->
            <li class="one-fourth animated" data-animate="flipInY" data-animate-delay="1000">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="img/team/team-2.jpg" alt="Team Member">
                    <i class="fa fa-tint"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="team-name">Peter Brown</span>
                <span class="team-job"></span>
                <ul class="social-icons">
                </ul><!-- End .social-icons -->
            </li><!-- End .one-fourth -->
            <li class="one-fourth animated" data-animate="flipInY" data-animate-delay="1500">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="img/team/team-3.jpg" alt="Team Member">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="team-name">Jane Red</span>
                <span class="team-job">r</span>
                <ul class="social-icons">
                </ul><!-- End .social-icons -->
            </li><!-- End .one-fourth -->
            <li class="one-fourth last animated" data-animate="flipInY" data-animate-delay="2000">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="img/team/team-4.jpg" alt="Team Member">
                    <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="team-name">Richard Blue</span>
                <span class="team-job"></span>
                <ul class="social-icons">
                </ul><!-- End .social-icons -->
            </li><!-- End .one-fourth -->
        </ul><!-- End .team -->

    </div><!-- End .container -->
</section>


<!-- OUR SKILLS -->
<section id="skills" class="sect-1"></section>


<!-- CAllOUT --><!-- End .image-callout -->


<!-- PRICING --><!-- RECENT POSTS --><!-- CONTACT -->
```

```
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3 class="title">Contact Us</h3>
            <p class="description">Please use the contact form below to email us.</p>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="php/send_message.php" class="contact-form">
            <div class="one-half animated" data-animate="fadeInDown">
                <span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name">
                </span>
                <span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
                </span>
                <span>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="subject">
                </span>
            </div><!-- End .one-third -->

            <div class="one-half last animated" data-animate="fadeInDown" data-animate-delay="1000">
                <span>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="message"></textarea>
                </span>
            </div><!-- End .one-half -->
            <button id="submit" type="submit" class="contact-button animated" data-animate="fadeInDown" data-animate-delay="1000">Send Message</button>
        </form>

    </div><!-- End .container -->

</section>


<!-- MAP -->
<div class="map-button">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> LOCATE US ON THE MAP
</div>
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div id="google-map"></div>
</div><!-- End .map-wrapper -->

<!-- MAP LOCATION WINDOW -->
<div id="content">
    <div id="siteNotice">
    </div>
    <h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Graduate School Of Motoring</h2>
    <div id="bodyContent">
        <p>This is us, drop by sometime.</p>
    </div>
</div><!--  End #content -->


<section class="footer">
    <img class="footer-logo" src="img/logo.png" width="50" alt="">
    <div class="address">
  Tel: 01474 332225</div><!-- End .address -->

    <ul class="social-icons">
    </ul>

    <div class="copy">© 2014 Gradute School Of Motoring</div>
</section>

<!-- JQUERY -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- PLUGINS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

<!-- THEME SCRIPT -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, just make the `<ul>` with a width wide enough to place all tabs in *one line*.

Simply add `width: 90%;` and `text-align: center;` to your `.main_menu` CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

u can remove `display: inline-block;` and `float: right;` from `.main_menu` class and add `margin-left` to the list with at last the width of the logo, plus `text-align: right;` if u want menu positions aligned to the right.

so this:

```
.main_menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

now looks like this:

```
.main_menu {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 150px; /* logo width + some padding from it */
    text-align: right;
}
```